# Fire a stream of bullets in spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit

Have a scenario where a player should be able to fire a stream of bullets one after the other. How do I achieve this? I don't want the player to be limited by the number of bullets he can fire .. i.e., I don't want to use an array for storing the bullets. Please advise the correct data structure for this scenario.

Comment: I suggest you create an `SKNode`, add the node to the scene, and then add the bullets to the node.

Comment: We need more detail on what you mean. Why do you need to store the bullets (if you are sub classing SKSpriteNode to implement them, their management can be handled there so no need to keep references to them)? If you do need to store them why are arrays not suitable (the upper size of a Swift array will not be your limiting factor)?

Comment: 0x141E - Will you be able to elaborate a little more?

Comment: Ali Beadle - yes, there is no need to keep references to them. I didn't quite follow the rest of your post. Can you please explain in detail? Appreciate your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

You can us an array or a collection. Once a bullet has left the screen bounds you can remove it from the scene, reposition it and add it again when you need the next bullet:

For example: Array with N elements [A,B,C, ...] move from left to right

```
start: A,B,C : X Position = 0; No sprite added to the scene

Iteration 1: A. X Position 0; scene.addChild(A)

Iteration 2: Move A: X Position 10; scene.addChild(B)

Iteration 3: Move A: X Position 20; Move B: X Position 10; scene.addChild(C)

...

Iteration N-1: Move A: X Position 0; X Position 480; Move B: X Position 470; Move C: X Position 460; ...

Iteration N: A.removeFromParent(), X Position 0; Move B: X Position 480; Move C: X Position 470; ...

Iteration N+1: scene.addChild(A), X Position 0; B.removeFromParent(), X Position 0; Move C: X Position 480; ...
```